# How to add new table in NopCommerce?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I am using NopCommerce.

How can I create new table in NopCommerce?

I have followed these steps.

1. Create The Entity Class (e.g Entity.cs)

   Path : `Nop/Core/Domain/Entity.cs`
2. Create The Mapping Class (e.g `EntityMap.cs`)

   Path : `Nop/Data/Mapping/EntityMap.cs`
3. Create a Model for MVC (e.g `EntityModel.cs`)

   Path : `Nop/Admin/Models/EntityModel.cs OR Nop/Web/Models/EntityModel.cs`
4. Create a validator for model (e.g `EntityValidator.cs`)

   Path : `Nop/Admin/Validators/EntityValidator.cs OR Nop/Web/Validators/EntityValidator.cs`
5. Create A Mapping Configuration On `AutoMapperStartupTask.cs` for Entity and Model

   Path : `Nop/Admin/Infrastructure OR Nop/Web/Infrastructure`
6. Apply Mapping between Model and Entity on `MappingExtensions.cs`

   Path : `Nop/Admin` OR `Nop/Web`
7. Create a service class and service interface (e.g `EntityService.cs` , `IEntityService.cs`)

   Path : `Nop/Services/EntityService.cs AND Nop/Services/IEntityService.cs`
8. Finally Create Controller and View for given model

But new table is not created. so what should be problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have found above thing at

http://pl-developer.blogspot.in/2013/02/how-to-add-new-table-with-model-map-to.html

Below blogger has written

> as Nop Commerce uses the very first release of MVC3, database
>   migration is not supported and you must make changes to database
>   tables by hand. Because MVC code-first must drop and recreate your
>   database for reflecting changes to your database.

Comment: Thank you so much.it will be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

Open this path ~\Nop.Web.Framework and open DependencyRegistrar.cs and register your service and interface like this

```
// UserMaster
builder.RegisterType<EntityService>().As<IEntityService ().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Create table in NopCommerce database and give name "Entity".

**Note:** Manually create table in database is necessary.

Finally create new controller and its View

**If you want to get to more detail**, Click [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=11&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiNpYaezPXOAhWKsI8KHSc2Cxk4ChAWCBwwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lateshtclick.com%2Fblogpost%2Fhow-to-add-new-tables-to-nopcommerce&usg=AFQjCNFme_dRu4dwVUKDRFqcgMxvDp_r9Q&sig2=uSiyZ9uSZf-TI6gszBDCrQ)!